# jquery vertically expanding and fading data via AJAX

Tags: jquery

Here is the envisioned code:

```
<div id="event1">
    <div class="control_bar"> Open Event </div>
    <div id="eventBody1">
    <!-- AJAX content will go here when it loads -->
    </div>
</div>
```

a few pointers:

1. `.control_bar` is always visible
2. `#event1` will have a border/background color or other styling to differentiate it.  Not sure if that's relevant
3. `#eventBody1` is visible if there's data initially, hidden if not
4. height of data received is indeterminate, could vary in height quite a bit

I would like to use jQuery to both fade in and expand the div as soon as the ajax comes in, and then fade out and contract when it's closed.  I would appreciate examples of this or links that are fairly simple.

Comment: So you wanna fetch the data and smoothly expand the height of the container or what?

Comment: excepting the "or what", yes exactly.  Well, and also fade in (or out on removing the data).
Also, thanks for editing the post to hightlight the classes

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS transitions:

```css
#eventBody1 {
  -webkit-transition: height 5s;
  -moz-transition: height 5s;
  transition: height 5s;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/4wwqt61k/

Comment: this does not work in my most recent version of FireFox.  Also, it doesn't fade in or out, and I'm hoping to see how it works in relationship to a $.ajax( ) call anyway